# Problemas na implementação de JSP usando Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Após executar a seguinte `jsp`:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hey!</title>
</head>
<body>

    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${session.loggedin == true}">
            <p>Welcome, ${session.username}. Say HEY to someone.</p>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <p>Welcome, anonymous user. Say HEY to someone.</p>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>

    <c:forEach items="${heyBean.allUsers}" var="user">
        <a href="
            <s:url action="say" method="post">
                <s:param name="username" value="session.username" />
                <s:param name="myFriend" value="${user}"/>
            </s:url>
            "><c:out value="${user}"/><br>
        </a>
    </c:forEach>

    <p><a href="<s:url action="index" />">Start</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Tenho o seguinte bug:
    According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-t%c3%adtulo/1911#1911

Answer (score -1):

Nas tags do Struts, as expressões são delimitadas por uma porcentagem: `%{...}`. Diferente das tags da JSTL que usam o cifrão: `${...}`.

Tente fazer isso no seu exemplo:

```xml
<s:param name="myFriend" value="%{user}"/>
```

Comment: <s:param name="myFriend" value="${user}"/>, esta linha fica como está e esta linha:
<c:out value="${user}"/><br> fica como disse.

Mas ocorrem os seguintes erros quando compilo: 

The first TextProvider in the ValueStack (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport) could not locate the message resource with key 'Username:'

Comment: @AndréLizardo É o contrário, as tags do struts são as que começam com `s:` e devem ter a porcentagem. As tags que começam com `c:` são da JSTL e podem usar a cifra. Sobre o outro erro que você obteve, ele não tem a ver com o código postado nesta pergunta. Deve ter um `label` em algum outro lugar e falta a entrada no arquivo de internacionalização (`.properties`).

Comment: Alguém tem ideia do motivo do *downvote*? Tem algo errado com a resposta?